# conversion of warnings to errors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, error-handling, warnings

In some of my functions I want to convert some warnings into errors. For example, if I want to throw an error when `str2func` yields a `MATLAB:str2func:invalidFunctionName` warning, I would do the following:

```
invalid_func_id = 'MATLAB:str2func:invalidFunctionName';
%hide warning of interest
warning('off', invalid_func_id);
%this might yield the warning of interest
predicate_func_try = str2func(predicate_func);
[~, warn_id] = lastwarn;
assert(~strcmp(warn_id, invalid_func_id)...
    , 'MyFunc:InvalidFunctionName'...
    , 'The predicate function %s does not have a valid name'...
    , predicate_func...
    );
warning on all
```

This works fine if I know that a particular block of code can give a small set of warnings. However it is verbose and probably doesn't scale to larger code blocks. Is there a better way of doing this? Ideally I would want a function which can turn certain warnings to errors in a whole block. It would allow me to modify my example to:

```
warnings2errors('MATLAB:str2func:invalidFunctionName');
predicate_func_try = str2func(predicate_func);
warnings2errors('off');
```

Comment: According to this thread - http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/158768 - your way is the only one.

Answer (score 6):

Another method would be to overload warning itself. See implementation of warning.m and warning2error.m below. The biggest side effect I see from this is that you will see an extra "warning.m" displayed on the stack for all warning messages.  Not sure if there's a way around that.  Also, you would need to disable the MATLAB:dispatcher:nameConflict warning since we're overloading a builtin.

EDIT: Just noticed on matlabcentral.com an undocumented use of the builtin warning that accomplishes this:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/158768
http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/trapping-warnings-efficiently/

```
>> warning('error','MATLAB:str2func:invalidFunctionName')
```

USAGE FROM COMMAND LINE

> > warning2error('add','MATLAB:str2func:invalidFunctionName')

Warning.m:

```
% Overload of warning.m to enable conversion of certain warnings to errors
% via warning2error.m
%
% Will want to disable warning "MATLAB:dispatcher:nameConflict" via command
% warning('off','MATLAB:dispatcher:nameConflict');
%
% Jesse Hopkins
% Oct. 2 2012

function varargout = warning(varargin)
    %check for component:mnemonic syntax
    if nargin >= 2 && ischar(varargin{1}) && any(regexp(varargin{1},'^(\w+:\w+){1,}$','start','once'))
        %we've captured  <component>[:<component>]:<mnemonic>syntax

        %check if this is in the list
        if warning2error('query',varargin{1})
            %YES, convert to error
            ME = MException(varargin{1},varargin{2:end});
            ME = ME.addCause(MException('Warning2Error:ConvertedWarning','Converted warning "%s" to error becuase it was registered via warning2error.m.',varargin{1}));
            ME.throwAsCaller;
        end
    end

    %pass through to built-in warning
    varargout{1:nargout} = builtin('warning',varargin{:});
end
```

Warning2Error.m:

```
%warning2error.m
%USAGE:
%   Add warnings to convert to errors.
%  warning2error('add','<component>[:<component>]:<mnemonic>',...
%
%   Remove warnings to convert to errors
%   warning2error('remove','<component>[:<component>]:<mnemonic>',...
%
%   Query warnings to convert to errors 
%   tf = warning2error('query','<component>[:<component>]:<mnemonic>')
%
%   Get entire list of warnings converted to errors
%   list = warning2error('get')
%
% Jesse Hopkins
% Oct 2 2012

function varargout = warning2error(op,varargin)
    persistent list;
    if isempty(list)
        list = {};
    end
    varargout={};

    switch lower(op)
        case 'add'
            list = unique([list(:);varargin(:)]);
        case 'remove'
            for i = 1:length(varargin)
                [tf idx] = ismember(varargin{i},list);
                allidx = 1:length(list);
                newidx = setdiff(allidx,idx);
                list = list(newidx);
            end
        case 'clear'
            list = {};
        case 'get'
            varargout{1} = list;
        case 'query'
            out = false(1,length(varargin));
            for i = 1:length(varargin)
                out(i) = ismember(varargin{1},list);
            end
            varargout{1} = out;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a clean way to do exactly what you want.  Depending on your reason for wanting to turn errors into warnings, you may be able to get by with:

```
dbstop if warning
```

or

```
dbstop if warning MyFunc:InvalidFunctionName
```

You can also look at `warning on stacktrace`, to get more infomrat6ion on warnings as they appear.

If you need an actual error message (not just a way to break into the debugger) then I'm actually pretty impressed with the method you included in the question.

Answer (score 2):

It was mentioned as an edit by jHops, but this technique is so simple, it deserves its own concise answer.

As (un)documented in https://undocumentedmatlab.com/articles/trapping-warnings-efficiently, to turn warnings to errors, simply do

```matlab
s = warning('error', 'MATLAB:nearlySingularMatrix');
```

where the second string is the warning ID itself. It can be found by `warning on verbose` in cmdline, and inspecting the warning message. In my experience, it can be further debugged by turning on `dbstop if error; dbstop if warning; dbstop if naninf`, depending on your issue.

This is a full example for inverting a matrix and checking if it's singular. The last line turns the warning-errors back to regular warnings. `s` can be either a single warning state as above, or an array.

```matlab
s = [warning('error', 'MATLAB:nearlySingularMatrix'), warning('error', 'MATLAB:singularMatrix')];
try
  Minv = inv(Mat);
  InvertFail = false;
catch
  InvertFail = true;
  return;
end
warning(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to generalise this somewhat. It works the following way (similar to `tic` and `toc`):

```
warn_ids = setwarnings2errors('MATLAB:str2func:invalidFunctionName');
predicate_func_try = str2func(predicate_func);
getwarnings2errors(warn_ids);
```

Between `setwarnings2errors` and `getwarnings2errors`, all warnings set will throw an error if they are the last warning thrown. Therefore it shouldn't be used in large blocks where many different warnings can happen. I implemented the functions the following way:

setwarnings2errors:

```
function warning_ids = setwarnings2errors(varargin)
warning_ids = cell(nargin, 1);
for x_ = 1:nargin
    local_arg = varargin{x_};
    assert(ischar(local_arg));
    evalin('caller', sprintf('warning off %s', local_arg));
    warning_ids{x_} = local_arg;
end
end
```

getwarnings2errors:

```
function getwarnings2errors(warning_ids)
[lastwarn_str, lastwarn_id] = evalin('caller', 'lastwarn');
num_warns = numel(warning_ids);
try
    for x_ = 1:num_warns
        local_warn = warning_ids{x_};
        assert(~strcmp(local_warn, lastwarn_id)...
            , lastwarn_id...
            , lastwarn_str...
            );
    end
catch m_e
    evalin('caller', 'warning on all');
    throwAsCaller(m_e);
end
evalin('caller', 'warning on all');
end
```